# Is there a Desktop-like view for JavaFx desktop application?

Tags: java, javafx, desktop-application

I will go straight to the point. I am building a server-client system that will basically be a cloud storage. Therefore, server will send client a list of files and folders at connection time and client will show them to the user.

What I am looking for is a JavaFx view that will show these contents in a desktop-like fashion: each of them with its own icon and a name under it.

I am confident there are better ways to do this than a complex ad-hoc GridView, but it seems I am unable to find them.

Hope someone will help me...

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: No at least not in controlsfx or the standard library and adjusting `GridView` is not that complicated, but may not be exactly what you need since in contrast to a desktop it automatically adds a scrollbar...

Comment: `desktop-like fashion` fashion are changing so fast .. what is this fashion you are talking about ? Plus, you should write a more specific problem to be on topic since asking for api or tutorial/guide is not on the topics of SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use flow pane of JavaFX, it will add children in flow. You can give icons to them on conditions like if you get the directory then give the folder icon else file icon like this.

Refer to this for the [Flow Pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/FlowPane.html)
 and [Layout building](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm)

Example :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DemoFile extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        Button button = new Button("File Name or folder name");
        button.setPrefSize(200, 200);
        flowPane.getChildren().add(button);
    }
    Scene scene = new Scene(flowPane);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Try this example in which I have added 20 buttons in flow pane but you can change the component as you wish you can also set the padding of flow pane to give the spacing between the children's of flow pane

Comment: You are welcome, this have enough to be an answer, but no idea if this is what OP wants.

Comment: Yup I also think so, but I can't comment on this because my reputation is low, still I wanted to give him some suggestion that's why I posted an answer

Comment: @AxelH I think he wants the look of my computer in JavaFX